# Eating on the Palace on Wheels, in Rajasthan, India if I have dietary restrictions

Tags: trains, indian-railways, dietary-restrictions, nostalgia

I've heard a lot about the train that was owned by a Maharaja and has become a major tourist attraction. I'm gluten allergic and have other dietary restrictions. I'm wondering if cooped up in a train would be a problem and even though the web site says they can accommodate dietary restrictions, how much flexibility is available. I'd like to hear from folks who have been on it.

Comment: About the close votes on this: I don't think this qualifies as opinion-based since there's an objective yes-or-no answer to factors such as gluten-free food.

Answer (score 5):

I can't give you any specific information about the Palace on Wheels, but I can tell you that Indian's are very accommodating to people with dietary restrictions.  Indian culture encourages individuality in religious practice, and that individuality often shows up as self imposed dietary restrictions ([Gandhi is an excellent example](http://www.gandhifoundation.net/about%20gandhi5.htm)).  In rural parts of India you will have difficulty communicating your specific dietary restrictions, but the Palace on Wheels is generally something that only foreign tourists or wealthy English speaking Indians take.  So, I expect that you won't have any problems getting properly fed aboard the train.

Comment: It might be needed to warn them ahead of time, so they have the right alternatives handy rather than having to improvise. (They can not run out to a shop, if traveling.)

Comment: Unfortunately it will depend much more on the dietary restrictions in question than this answer makes it seem.  There are dietary restrictions that they will just not understand - which can make it exceedingly hard to get anyone to accommodate.  I've seen this when the problem is specific spices, or something that was trace amounts to begin with - something larger is easier to avoid.